# An equivalence of two conditions about simply connected domain

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

Recently, I read a book about Complex Analysis. The author gave two definitions of simply connected domain.

One is the complement of the domain (based on $\overline{\mathbb{C}}$) is connected.

The other is that the inside of every Jordan curve in the domain is in the domain.

The author did not give a proof. I tried hard with elementary topological tools but failed. Could anyone teach me how to prove the equivalence of above two definitions?
Very appreciated!!

Comment: You need two facts - one is that in the extended plane any (plane so not containing infinity) and say plane closed set has only one unbounded component since you could connect points through infinity - this is not true in the plane as the complement of a strip, for example, has two unbounded plane components, but as above you connect them through the point at infinity; second is the Jordan curve theorem (a Jordan curve splits the plane into two domains, one bounded called inside, one unbounded called outside and both inside and outside in extended plane are homeomorphic with a disc)

Answer (score -3):

These two are not equivalent. Consider the set $U = \{z\in\mathbb{C} \mid |z| > 1\}.$ Then $\mathbb{C}\setminus U$ is the unit disk, which is surely connected.

But there are many Jordan curves whose interiors lie outside the domain; for instance, take an origin centered circle of radius 2, whose interior includes the point $0$ which lies outside your domain $U.$

Comment: The definition is based on extend complex plane. You mentioned U is not simply connected since C\U and $\infty$ is not connected.